# DNS resolution failing on iPhone using VPN

Tags: iphone, dns, vpn

I have an iphone application that calls the c function getHostByName to resolve a hostname to an ipaddress.  This works beautifully once, but fails from then onwards with a host does not exist error.  It sounds like I could be getting different results depending on the calling thread as expressed in [iPhone DNS resolution, not all A records returned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5079418/1179517).

The iPhone is using the Cisco AnyConnect VPN software and this works fine (resolves always) over a wifi network, but not over a 3G network under iOs 5+.  Under iOs4.3 it would always fail the second time.

Has anyone else experienced weirdness like this?  It would seem as though the network/vpn configuration is correct or else it wouldn't work the first time???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone looks at this.... The problem was with the Cisco VPN host having a split dns configured - and the default domains not being set properly.